# How to Embed a List of Specialized Classes Into an Entity

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Here below is a simple model for a pet shop...

**Pet Class**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Embeddable
public abstract class Pet {

  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  private String name;
}
```

**Cat Class**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Embeddable
public class Cat extends Pet {

  @Column(name = "call")
  private String call;
}
```

**PetShop Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pet_shop")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PetShop {

  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(
      name = "pets",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pet_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
  private List<Pet> pets= new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**PetShopRepository Interface**

```
public interface PetShopRepository 
  extends JpaRepository<PetShop, Long> {}
```

... and here is how to create a `PetShop` with at least one `Pet`:

```
final Pet pet = new Cat();
pet.setName("cat");
pet.setCall("meow");

final PetShop petShop = new PetShop();
petShop.getPets().add(pet);

petShopRepositiry.save(petShop);
```

So far so good... but when I try to retrieve the `PetShop`...

```
final PetShop petShop = petShopRepository.findById(shopId)
    .orElseThrow(() -> new ShopNotFoundException(shopId));
```

I always get the following error:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface:
  : com.mytest.persistence.model.Pet; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException:
    Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface:  : com.myTest.persistence.model.Pet
```

Of course the message is clear... but I'm wondering whether it is possible to have a collection of pets, each potentially referencing a different specialized class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work, I just made class `Pet` concrete (removed `abstract`):

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Embeddable
public class Pet {

  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  private String name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use  @JsonIgnore in the Petshop class. Use @OneToMany relationship annotation then it should work. Like this

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.Lazy, mappedBy = "pets")
@JsonIgnore
private List<Pet> pets= new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because `Pet` cannot be abstract. In my case, I just made `Pet` concrete and my implementation worked as expected. Thank u anyway :-)